# Regex_replace not replacing correctly in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to get the following Regex expression to work with Oracle SQL:

```
select regexp_replace('    "abc_78": 123, ', '.*?abc.*?: (.*?),.*', '\1') from dual;
select regexp_replace('    "abc_78": 123, "def_79": [', '.*?abc.*?: (.*?),', '\1') from dual;
```

The first one returning `"123"` (which I deem correct) while the second one returning `"123 "def_79": ["`.

What's the issue at stake here? A bad regex or some weird functioning of Oracle? The regex seems to work well when tried against Sublime Text. I'm running this query directly off Oracle SQL Developer.

Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Ah, I kinda saw that coming... Argh..

Comment: Wait a sec, [this reference in the *Perl-Influenced Extensions in Oracle Regular Expressions* part](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm) says it is OK to use lazy quantifiers. What result do you expect for the 2nd input?

Comment: I think that maybe I may be a bit off here. I wanted to select 123 from those "abc_<something>: 123" strings. Am I correct in using regexp_replace for that?

Comment: Maybe `.*abc[^:]*: *([^,]*),.*` will help? You did not match the whole rest of the string after the comma.

Comment: Or `SELECT regexp_substr('    "abc_78": 123, "def_79": [', 'abc_[^:]*:\s*(\d+)', 1,1,NULL,1) from dual;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's replacing correctly.

```
select regexp_replace('    "abc_78": 123, "def_79": [', '.*?abc.*?: (.*?),', '\1') from dual;
```

First: It (regex engine) finds '"abc_78": 123' where 123 is group $1.
Then it replaces 'abc_78: 123' with group 1 which is 123.

And you have little diffrence in those regex patterns like:

```
'.*?abc.*?: (.*?),.*', '\1') from dual;
'.*?abc.*?: (.*?),', '\1') from dual;
```

missing .* in 2nd pattern.

If You want to retrieve 123 from this strings, is better to use `regex_substr`

```
select regexp_substr('    "abc_78": 123, ','\d+',1,2) from dual;
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. So I'll slightly rephrase my question. What I'm looking for is to find and print 123 in that string. What other SQL function (on Oracle, or standard if such exists) should I be using for that?

Comment: I see, just one more thing. That last parameter, 2, seems kinda dodgy. Wouldn't there be a better of way, maybe using capture groups, to capture the 123?

Comment: In this substr function which i write, 2 means 2nd occurence in string (in this case 123) 1st is 78, 2nd is 123. Of course there are better ways, but without dev environment (sqldeveloper f.e.) This is all i can give.